# Error while trying to expand the HttpURLConnection class

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to create a custom version of the HttpURLConnection class.

The class for now looks like this:

```
package com.removed;

import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public abstract class MyHUC extends HttpURLConnection {

    public MyHUC(URL url) {
        super(url);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

}
```

But when I call:

```
MyHUC connection = (MyHUC) url.openConnection();
```

I get the following error:

```
02-13 14:42:23.639: E/AndroidRuntime(4735): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-760
02-13 14:42:23.639: E/AndroidRuntime(4735): java.lang.ClassCastException: libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl cannot be cast to com.removed.MyHUC
02-13 14:42:23.639: E/AndroidRuntime(4735):     at com.removed.TVSlideActivity.DownloadFile(TVSlideActivity.java:603)
02-13 14:42:23.639: E/AndroidRuntime(4735):     at com.removed.TVSlideActivity.access$9(TVSlideActivity.java:588)
02-13 14:42:23.639: E/AndroidRuntime(4735):     at com.removed.TVSlideActivity$5.run(TVSlideActivity.java:337)
02-13 14:42:23.639: E/AndroidRuntime(4735):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

This is driving me crazy, I've been looking for a solution on the net for hours now, can any of the experts here enlighten me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current setup the `URL` class knows nothing about your custom URL connection class. The call you are making returns a `URLConnection` type (which happens to be a `HttpURLConnection`, but thats an implementation detail). You cannot cast the resulting connection to a `MyHUC` type because it *isn't one*. It's important to remember that for the future.

As it so happens, there ***is*** a way to specify a custom URL connection class for the `URL` class. You have to utilize an alternate constructor to create the URL, supplying a `URLStreamHandler`. Sample code is shown below:

```
public class MyURLConnection extends HttpURLConnection {

    public MyURLConnection(URL arg0) {
        super(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public void disconnect() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean usingProxy() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void connect() throws IOException {
    }
}

public class MyURLStreamHandler extends URLStreamHandler {

    public MyURLStreamHandler() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected URLConnection openConnection(URL arg0) throws IOException {
        return new MyURLConnection(arg0);
    }
}
```

And used such:

```
final URL url = new URL("http", "www.google.com", -1, "",
        new MyURLStreamHandler());
final MyURLConnection conn = (MyURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is much better!

My only problem now is to call the default "connect" and "disconnect" methods... and they are abstract methods...

I'd actually like a copy of HttpURLConnection that behaves exactly like the original by default, and then only replace a couple of methods.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

`url.openConnection()` doesn't return `MyHUC` type of object, so you cannot safely cast it to that class. Please read above article to get a grip how inheritance works.

Comment: I understand, even if it sounds weird to me since it's a child of HttpURLConnection... thanks for the hint!

Comment: when in doubt, use instanceof operator, to see if you can cast one object into another